# How do I access a 2D array's range in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Given a 2D array, a[m][n] where m,n > 0, how do I access specific portions of that array (as I would in Matlab or Python, for example):

```
a[2:5][3:]
```

I realize that the `slice()` command works for one dimensional arrays but I can't get it to do what I want with higher dimensions.

Is this (easily) possible within Javascript?

Comment: Check this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript

Comment: @bksi Thanks, but I know how to make an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a.slice(2,3).map(function(m) {return m.slice(3);});
```

Assumes relatively up-to-date browser and/or shim.